# Parse an element in a list and store the result in a dictionary

Tags: python, parsing, return

I need to import a class from a separate file (which I did), have it parse an element in a list, and store that parsed file as a dictionary.

I need your help with this. I thought that there would be a return but there is not, so I don't know what I am supposed to do. I assume that it is possible and I just don't know how.

The code I have so far is this:

```
class GCCCOMPARE():
    def __init__(self, list):
        self.GCCLIST = list 
        self.compare()
        self.GCCN = []
        self.GCCPLUS = []


    def compare(self):
        n=0
        while n<size(self.GCCLIST):
            self.GCCN=self.GCCLIST[n]
            self.GCCPLUS=self.GCCLIST[n+1]
            GCCFORMAT.__init__(GCCN)
```

And the code in the other file I was given is this:

```
class GCCFORMAT():
    def __init__(self, file):
        #print"New GCC Load"
        self.pList = [];
        self.dList = [];
        self.file = file;
        self.parse()

    def parse(self):
        with open(self.file, "r") as icdhelper:
            for line in icdhelper:
                sArr = line.split()
                self.pList.append(PARAM(sArr[0], sArr[4], sArr[2], sArr[3], sArr[6], sArr[7]))
```

I doubt this will be difficult for anyone experienced, but even so thanks a lot guys!

Comment: You need to change your title of your question to something more descriptive of the problem.

Comment: Good question, but would you please consider updating the title to reflect the actual question?

Comment: You want to avoid naming variables `list`; you are masking the built-in type and confusing others reading your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an *instance* of the `GCCFORMAT` class, it'll do the parsing for you and store the results in an instance attribute, `pList`. Simply access that attribute:

```
gcc_format = GCCFORMAT(GCCN)
results = gcc_format.pList
```

Comment: thank you! i knew it would be simple.  sorry it was so noobish, but hey gotta start somewhere right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible fix:

GCCCOMPARE.py

```
import GCCFORMAT
class GCCCOMPARE():
  def __init__(self, list):
    self.GCCLIST = list
    self.GCCDICT = {}
    self.compare()

  def compare(self):
    for i,element in enumerate(self.GCCLIST):
      data = GCCFORMAT.GCCFORMAT(element)
      self.GCCDICT.update({i:data.pList})
```

GCCFORMAT.py

```
class GCCFORMAT():
  def __init__(self, file):
    #print"New GCC Load"
    self.pList = [];
    self.dList = [];
    self.file = file;
    self.parse()

  def parse(self):
    with open(self.file, "r") as icdhelper:
      for line in icdhelper:
        sArr = line.split()
        self.pList.append([sArr[0], sArr[4], sArr[2], sArr[3], sArr[6], sArr[7]])
```

temp0.txt

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

temp1.txt

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Then you can use the classes above as follows:

```
import GCCCOMPARE
somevariable = GCCCOMPARE.GCCCOMPARE(["temp0.txt","temp1.txt"])
desired_dictonary = somevariable.GCCDICT
```

Output is

```
desired_dictionary = {0: [['0', '4', '2', '3', '6', '7']], 1: [['0', '4', '2', '3', '6', '7']]}
```